# Samba and Windows Computer Account Passwords

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, samba

Is there a way to make a samba client participating in an Active Directory environment change its computer account password in the domain on a regular basis?  (More information about computer account passwords [in this Microsoft blog.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/02/15/test2.aspx))

We clean up "stale" computer accounts occasionally, and we identify candidates for cleanup by the age of the computer account password.  This works great for Windows, but we find our non-Windows systems don't manage that value like Windows does.  I know the setting to make a NetApp Filer maintain its password (options cifs.weekly_W2K_password_change on), just looking for the same type of setting on samba or other *nix systems that can participate in Active Directory.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cron-job with `net ads changetrustpw` run as root in it should accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  Will give it a try and post results, sounds like that might do it.

Comment: Took me a while to try this, but this did exactly what I needed.  Thanks again!